# Convert simple list comprehension into for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

My objective is transform this list comprehension into for loops :

```
[[x * y for x in  [1, 2]] for y in [3, 4, 5]]
# gives [[3,6], [4,8], [5,10]]
```

The only thing i can find :

```
List = []
for y in [3, 4, 5]:
    for x in [1, 2]:
        List.append([y * x])
# Gives [[3], [6], [4], [8], [5], [10]]
```

I feel silly but i struggle to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a temporary list in between the for-loops:

```
List = []
for y in [3, 4, 5]:
   l = []
   for x in [1, 2]:
       l.append(x*y)
   List.append(l)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 6], [4, 8], [5, 10]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! It seems obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the square brackets

```
List = []
for y in [3, 4, 5]:
    for x in [1, 2]:
        List.append(y * x)
```

Adding a square bracket around a calculation makes it a list in python